# Calculating area between two Lorenz curves (which may be intersecting) in R

Tags: r, area, inequality

I am trying to write codes for calculating the area included between two Lorenz curves.
I need to repeat the procedure several times: one reference curve will stay the same while the second will change iteratively.

The point is that the two curves might intersect once or more, and this makes a significant difference in performing the calculation of the area.

I have the coordinates of the two Lorenz curves for cumulative percentages of population (0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1) so I am working in the discrete since those curves are piece-wise linear.

Probably, the best solution would be a function assessing the presence of intersection points for separate intervals (0, 0.2), (0.2, 0.4), (0.4, 0.6) and so on.

Any idea on how to write a script for a similar purpose?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to find the intersection points. For each x value, find the absolute value of the difference between the two curves. Use the [trapezoidal rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule) to estimate the area of the curve defined by the differences.

Comment: Thank you Kent. Isn't this only an approximation to the value of the area? I would go for something more precise. That's why i thought about the cruciality of the intersection points.

Comment: Moreover I am in the discrete. I have 6 coordinates, not the entire function. Maybe your suggestion works once I have generated the function. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: Right, my suggestion will give an error on the sections where the curves cross. If you have the same X-values for each curve, finding the crossing points seems pretty straightforward; if you add those X values then you can apply trapezoidal rule.

Comment: See this answer for help with interpolation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31404679/can-ggplot2-find-the-intersections-or-is-there-any-other-neat-way/31405109#31405109